# Error: Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying... with cygwin64\bin\7z

Tags: flutter, dart, windows-10

After setting up flutter on my Win 10 laptop... I'm getting the following error when I try to run it or the doctor...

```
D:\src\flutter>flutter                                                                                                                                                                              Checking Dart SDK version...                                                                                                                                                                        Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 2f0af3715217a0c2ada72c717d4ed9178d68f6ed...                                                                                                                Unzipping Dart SDK...                                                                                                                                                                               Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline: D:\Programs\cygwin64\bin\7z.                                                                                                                     At D:\src\flutter\bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1:77 char:5                                                                                                                                        +     & 7z x $dartSdkZip "-o$cachePath" -bd | Out-Null
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (D:\Programs\cygwin64\bin\7z:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantActivateDocumentInPipeline

c
                                                                                                                                                                                                    Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ...                                                                                                                                                     Checking Dart SDK version...                                                                                                                                                                        Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 2f0af3715217a0c2ada72c717d4ed9178d68f6ed...
```

I've flutter in my path already.

Not sure why it is looking for 7z in my Cygwin folder -  D:\Programs\cygwin64\bin\7z !!

Appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved after I removed my Cygwin paths from the PATH.